ULP circuitry for a telematics unit
I am in the process of developing an ultra-low-power input circuitry for a telematics unit. The device will be connected to 24V truck battery and should be completely disconnected from the battery if the ignition wire is low.
My idea is to use the ignition wire to connect and disconnect the device from the battery, i.e. if the ignition is LOW it should be disconnected. If ignition wire is HIGH, it should be connected.
We need to be able to use the battery power some time after ignition is off. So, basically, the device will sense that ignition is off, then do some shutdowns of the peripherals and then turn itself off.
I am thinking of using a MOSFET with the gate connected to ignition.
Are there any best practices or any off-the-shelf circuits that can do the job?

why not use the ignition wire for power?

We need to be able to use the battery power some time after ignition is off. So, basically, the device will sense that ignition is off, then do some shutdowns of the peripherals and then turn itself off.

add that to your question ... it does not belong in a comment
